# How to secure application Java code from user code?

Tags: java, security

In our app, application loads user module using custom class loader. What would be the best way to protect wild behavior of the user module? We want to prevent:

- user code to modify any application code. We have some singletons, and user may access it using e.g. reflection to get some instances and change e.g. some critical configuration; or replace some guard code. Since the classloader is written by me, so I can prevent loading any class that is critical.
- user code should access only some folders; if possible. So it behave like unix user :)

Comment: The [`SecurityManager`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html) would be the place to start.

Comment: A modular application with **OSGi** would be nice. There are several runtime containers for OSGi like felix. Every module (OSGi "bundle") is quite isolated. Your singletons would become services. Activate/deactivate and dependencies are managed.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to set a `SecurityManager`. This is because the Java class library contains global state. You will also need to ensure your code does not use its privileges to expose itself through this state. In addition some global state is not security checked, for instance through "`AppContext`" and the current thread.

Usually the `package.access` security property is used to hide internal code within a parent class loader context. This isn't a bad idea if the potentially malicious code is loaded through a non-child class loader.

Note, if you pass an instance of your hidden code, malicious code can use `Object.getClass`, `Class.getMethods`, etc., to explore the public interface. `Class.getClassLoader` is checked, but make sure there aren't other outlets, such as through the thread context class loader (though `Thread.getContextClassLoader` strangely has a security check, its use is to publish the class loader).